# Enumerator chain starting with find

Tags: ruby

There's on case of enumerator chain I can't get my head around:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].find.map { |x| x * x }
#=> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

This returns the array of initial value squares, but I would expect it to return just the `[1]`

I tried to deconstruct everything and this is what I achieved: `.map` is called on a `find` enumerator for the original array. It calls `each` on itself to get values for iteration. `each` on enumerator delegates iteration to method for which enumerator was created, i.e. `find`. `find` gets first element of array, yields it up, and it keeps being yielded until it reaches the block in the example. The value gets squared, block returns it, underlying `each` block in `map` definition returns [1], it drops down to the `find`, and since it's `true` in a boolean sense, I expect `find` to return at this point, effectively ending iteration, but somehow it keeps feeding values from the array all the way up to the `map` block.

This is not a real-world example, I'm just trying to understand how to read these chains correctly, and this case got me confused.

**UPD**

Since it was suggested several times that `find` being called without a block returns 'default' enumerator, here's an example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].find
#=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:find>

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].find.each { |x| x < 4 }
#=> 1
```

Comment: Calling `find` without a block makes not much sense, it returns [default `EACH_ENUMERATOR`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) (click on “show source”.)

Comment: Nitpicking, but `find` would return a single element (`1`), not an array (`[1]`).

Comment: @mudasobwa `[1,2,3,4,5].find` returns `#<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:find>`, and there's just `RETURN_ENUMERATOR` in the source. Maybe I'm not looking int the right direction? But yeah, it makes no sense, it's just a synthetic example to illustrate some strange behavior.

Comment: @Stefan `map` is the method that dictates what will be returned by the whole statement, if I understand everything right. But `find` would internally return just 1, yes.

Comment: You need to pass the block like this `p [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].find  { |x| x.eql?2 }`, that's what he says!

Comment: `map` collects the result, you are calling find method which returns the enumerable objects, this becomes the receiver to map function, now map collects the result of `|x| x * x` and return the result array.

Comment: Not really a generalizable example, it's more of a language quirk if you ask me. `find` could've well returned either the first value or an empty array, just depends on the implementation of `find` without being fed a block.

Comment: @JonathanAllard find without a block returns enumerator and `map` is called on it. `find` that I'm speaking about is called **with** a block from inside this enumerator, if I understood everything right.

Comment: @Roman Your first sentence is correct, the other seems not. `find` has not been called with a block. You're calling find without a block as argument, so it will by default of not having that argument, return a default enumerator. Then pass the result to `.map`.

Comment: @JonathanAllard I'm not speaking about `find` in the ruby snippet I proivided. As I said it returns enumerator, and I'm not sure that it's default :each enumerator, at least running `[1,2,3].find` returns :find enumerator. When I said that find is called with a block, I'm speaking of this line in `enum.c`: `return rb_block_call(e->obj, meth, argc, argv, func, arg);`, line 482

Comment: @Roman: there's no such line in ruby master's `enum.c`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/f0137ba8cdd805249a55d371aa2309f5622b7f70/enumerator.c#L482 It's called from `enumerator_block_call` which is called from `enumerator_each`, which is enumerator's implementation of an `each`, which in turn is being called from `collect` iterator within `enum.c`. That is, if I understood all of these correctly, my C skills are sub par to say the least.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev oh, it seems I wrote `enum.c` instead of `enumerator.c` in the comment you replied to, sorry. My last comment has a link to the line in `enumerator.c` I was talking about.

Comment: @Roman: nah, it's a wrong path. `collect` is an alias for `map`. But you were investigating `find`, I thought?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm trying to get a grasp on the whole data flow in this statement. So it seems to me that `collect` is called on `#<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:find>`, it calls `each` on itself, which delegates to `find` on the original array.

Comment: @Roman: ok, now I'm confused too. Hang on :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126648/discussion-between-roman-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out.

The reason `find` does not terminate the iteration after the first value is processed by block, is that `collect_i` iterator within `collect` aka `map` method of Enumerable module explicitly returns `nil` after every iteration, no matter what was the returning value of a block provided with a call to `map` or `collect`. Here it is, taken from `enum.c`:

```
static VALUE
collect_i(RB_BLOCK_CALL_FUNC_ARGLIST(i, ary))
{
    rb_ary_push(ary, enum_yield(argc, argv));

    return Qnil;
}
```

So internal call to `find` on the initial array always gets `nil` as a result of yielding a value, and thus doesn't stop iteration until the last element is processed. This is easy to prove by downloading ruby as archive and modifying this function like this:

```
static VALUE
collect_i(RB_BLOCK_CALL_FUNC_ARGLIST(i, ary))
{
    rb_ary_push(ary, enum_yield(argc, argv));

    return ary;
}
```

After saving and building ruby from modified source, we get this:

`irb(main):001:0> [1,2,3,4,5].find.map { |x| x*x }
=> [1]`

Another interesting thing, is that Rubinius implements `collect` exactly like this, so I think there's a chance that MRI and Rubinius produce different results for this statement. I don't have a working Rubinius installation right now, but I will check for this when I'll have an oppoprtunity and update this post with result.

Not sure if this will ever be of any use to anyone, except maybe for satisfying one's curiosity, but still :)